# Invaild value of min and max using repeat until loop in pascal

Tags: loops, pascal

I need use loop from title,but I get incorrect value of result, under my code,please for suggestion, when i use a for everything is ok

```
const
  licz_l = 5;
var
  x, suma, min, max: longint;
  tab: array [1..5] of longint;
begin
  randomize();
  suma := 0;
  x := 0;
  repeat 
    tab[x] := random(100);
    suma := suma + tab[x];
    write({'wylosowane liczby : ',}tab[x],';');
    min := tab[1];
    max := tab[1];
    if (tab[x] < min) then
      min := tab[x];
      // max:=tab[1];
    if (max < tab[x]) then
      max := tab[x];
    x := x + 1;
  until x = licz_l;
  writeln('');
  writeln('srednia : ', suma / licz_l : 4 : 4);
  writeln('min : ', min, #9, 'max : ', max);
end.
```

New code with second loop [for], but like I write, is a posibility to use only one loop[repeat until] to getvthe same effect?

```
const
  licz_l = 5;
var
  x, suma, min, max: longint;
  tab: array [0..4] of longint;
begin
  randomize();
  suma := 0;
  x := 0;
  repeat 
    tab[x] := random(100);
    suma := suma + tab[x];
    write({'wylosowane liczby : ',}tab[x],';');
    x := x + 1;
  until x = licz_l;
  
  min := tab[0];
  max := tab[0];
  
  for x := 0 to licz_l-1 do
  begin
    if (tab[x] < min) then
      min := tab[x];
    if (max < tab[x]) then
      max := tab[x];
  end;

  writeln('');
  writeln('srednia : ',suma/licz_l:4:4);
  writeln('min : ',min,#9,'max : ',max);
end.
```

Comment: [How to debug Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+debug+pascal) ?

Comment: Can you share more details?  (Because this is not showing errors: https://onlinegdb.com/0OE24Ww9M )

Comment: With `x:=0;` it looks like the first `tab[x]` will be out of bounds.

Comment: You have a logic error in that you reset `min:=tab[1]` and `max:=tab[1]` **on every round**. Then you are comparing new values with these ones. E.g. if min becomes 7 on first round, next round the value is 1, ok min becomes 1, but then the next round you set min again to 7, you read e.g. 5 and set min to 5, you have lost the min=1 value. As this is your homework, I leave it to you to modify as needed. As others have noted, you can not start with index 0 since your array is indexed 1..5.

Comment: Btw, if you want to edit your question, look for the "Edit" button beneath the tags of your question.

Comment: I modify my code with "for loop", values are correct, but I wondering about that if I can use only one loop [repeat until] to solve that subject? can I please for more suggestion.New code i paste to under main question Eng is not my native language,sorry for grammar

Comment: @MarioMateaș my problem is a incorrect  value of min and max if i want to use only one loop [repeat until], like write Tom Brunberg in my first code  i have logical error with reset min and max innevery round. I try to find idea to resolve case only with "repeat until" .Of course with x :=0 and array index from 0 to 4

Comment: case resolved, modyfing code in main question - used only one loop

Comment: Glad you solved it, and you are welcome to post your own answers. However, answers must not be posted in the question! Please edit once more by removing your answers from your question post, and enter your answer as an answer post.

Answer (score 0):

```
const
licz_l=5;
var
x,suma,min,max: longint;
tab: array [0..4] of longint;
begin
randomize();
suma:=0;
x:=0;
  repeat 
    tab[x]:=random(100);
    suma:=suma+tab[x];
    write((*'wylosowane liczby : ',*)tab[x],';');
    x:=x+1;
  until x=licz_l;
  
  min:=tab[0];
  max:=tab[0];
  
  for x:=0 to licz_l-1 do
    begin
      if (tab[x]<min) then
      min:=tab[x];
      if (max<tab[x]) then
      max:=tab[x];
    end;

  writeln('');
  writeln('srednia : ',suma/licz_l:4:4);
  writeln('min : ',min,#9,'max : ',max);
end.

Or

const
  licz_l = 5;
var
  x, suma, min, max: longint;
  tab: array [0..4] of longint;
begin
  randomize();
  suma := 0;
  x := 0;
  min := 99;
  max := 0;
  repeat 
    tab[x] := random(100);
    suma := suma + tab[x];
    write((*'wylosowane liczby : ',*)tab[x],';');
    //min := tab[0];
    //max := tab[0];
    if (tab[x] < min) then
      min := tab[x];
    if (max < tab[x]) then
      max := tab[x];
    x := x + 1;
  until x = licz_l;
  writeln('');
  writeln('srednia : ', suma / licz_l : 4 : 4);
  writeln('min : ', min, #9, 'max : ', max);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to correct your first code (with a single loop).

1. Remove the lines within the loop: `min := tab[1];` and `max := tab[1];`
   Initialize `min` and `max` **before the loop**, with values that are,

- on one hand > maximum value that `random(100)` may return, and
- on other hand < minimum value that `random(100)` may return.

or

2. Assign `min` and `max` **unconditionally** with the first value, but **only the first time** your loop runs (if x = 0).